# Best method for creating a custom Wordpress post type just like a page

Tags: wordpress

I have a site where I need to add a post type that has all of the exact same features as a normal PAGE in Wordpress but is a post type of "AGENT".

I thought the easiest way to do this would have been to create a normal page with a specific category that I could reference elsewhere in the code...but I know categories are not available on pages.

Is the best way to do this with a custom post type, or is there an easier method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *we can* [add categories to pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/34531).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse34528_add_page_cats' );

function wpse34528_add_page_cats()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
```

Or you can create a [Custom Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and assign it to Pages.

Or create the [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and configure it as you wish.

Comment: More reading is due but I think either Custom Taxonomy or Category on a page may be in order here!  I didn't even know you could do that with WP.  Thanks!